# Google Chrome different video players

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, video-player

How come google chrome can play the following video:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

But not when I try to do it myself?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="500" height="300" controls autoplay>
        <source src="Videos/SampleVIDEO1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser doesn't support video, you may download the video instead: <a href="http://localhost:2421/Videos/SampleVIDEO1.mp4">Click</a>.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add <html lang="en"> instead of <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: That doesn't matter for the result.

Comment: Allright, I found out that if you have the same player with the same file open for a couple of times, only one player will be able to play it in Chrome. But then again, I'm still having a problem displaying one video on a page:

https://www.ictz.nl/over-ICTZ/het-bedrijf

Check this page on Google Chrome and any other browser and try to play the video... :S